# jQuery prefill form field on a popup page

Tags: javascript, jquery

My explanation below, hope it's clear.

On the base page, there is a link with ID 123, and click to open enquiry page:

```
<a href="/enquiry/?id=123"></a>
```

On the enquiry page, there is a form:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="id" value="">
</form>
```

Question - Is it possible to pass the ID value "123" to the enquiry page, and prefill the  field? make it like below:

```
<input type="text" name="id" value="123">
```

Anyone help please, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}
```

calling `getQueryVariable("id")` - would return "123".

```
$('.txt1').val(getQueryVariable("id"));
```

html :-

```
<input type="text" name="id" value="" class="txt1">
```